# Should the "women" tag be changed to something more age-neutral?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

### [women](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/women) has been merged into [gender](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender)

---

Whenever someone calls someone else a "women", I automatically think of someone over the age of 20, I would find it odd to call a child a "women" (as they are more like a "girl"). With the usage of the [women](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/women) tag, should this tag be called [women](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/women) or should it be renamed to something age neutral such as [female](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/female) (or [females](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/females)).

Alternatively, if the [women](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/women) is good enough, should we also have a [girl](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/girl) for younger people, or would we just use the [women](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/women) tag for all ages?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This tag actually makes me really uncomfortable.

I'd prefer it just didn't exist at all. The very fact that it's only currently used on three questions would make it easy to kill and, to add to that, if it was applied to every question that was actually about females, it'd essentially become a meta tag. I also find it somewhat amusing that there isn't a [men](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/men) tag.

I vote we just get rid of it entirely and let the gender of the person be clear in the question itself.

Comment: I wanted to propose this too however I believe that you should that certain situations may be different depending on the gender, however I have no objections to removing it entirely.

Comment: Tags aren't supposed to be used to clarify a question they should be used to categorize questions so that people can search for relevant questions later. It's entirely possible to be an active user on a site and be entirely oblivious to a questions tags.

Comment: I agree, I don't see much use in the tag that [tag:gender] doesn't already offer, that is signifying that gender is an important factor in the question.

Comment: +1 because YAAAAAAASSSSSSS.  I believe that if it's a question where gender is actually that important maybe we should just have a gender tag instead of a male/female tag.

Comment: I votes to retire this barely-used tag since "gender" covers all its applications.

Comment: OK, so, I think I'm going to merge "women" in to "gender" and create a "men" synonym, too... Thoughts?

Comment: I think women would usually be a 'meta tag', which are site-wide considered to be a bad idea (TM). The main sign is that it really doesn't help, it's not like people think "oh, I know stuff about women, let me look for the women tag..." (and if they do, well then perhaps they shouldn't think that!)

Answer (score 5):

Something that oddly wasn't mentioned yet... We have [gender](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) that should work in all cases where gender is a significant factor...

Answer (score 3):

On top of what Catija said, the tag is essentially a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), as it can't be used on its own. That's why we should kill it with fire altogether, instead of changing it to some more age-neutral tag.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a meta tag and propose we burn it.

I don't think it serves a decent distinction purpose either, and the topic of "women" is so hilariously broad that it doesn't even categorize properly.